# Splunk - Using Report as a Saved Search

Tags: splunk, splunk-dashboard

I have a new *personal* Dashboard (i.e. listed under the "Yours" tab in "Dashboards"). I am trying to reference report I have created. This is currently a *personal* report (i.e. listed under the "Yours" tab in "Reports"). In an effort to reference this report, I have added the following to the dashboard's source:

```
{
  ...,
  "dataSources": {
    "myReport": {
      "type:": "ds.savedSearch",
      "options": {
        "ref": "Team - Weekly Stats",
        "app": "team_bears"
      }
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

When I visit the "Data Overview" in the dashboard designer, I do not see my report listed under "Saved Search" like I would expect. In addition to the above, I tried the following:

- I thought it might be because I was trying to use a "personal" report. So, I chose a different report that was listed under the "All" tab under "Reports". However, that report did not appear under "Saved Search" in the the designer.
- I thought perhaps the spaces or "-" was throwing it off. So, I tried referencing a report that was named `team_stats`. However, it still did not appear under "Saved Search" in the designer.

What am I missing? Why can't I use my report as a saved search in my dashboard?

Comment: Are you trying to embed a *Dashboard* in another Dashboard, or a *Report* in a Dashboard?

Comment: @warren I am trying to use a _Report_ in my dashboard as a data source.

Comment: thanks for the clarification - embedding Dashboards isn't possible, but Reports are :)